# Separate hashes from array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, json, hash

I am using google charts api with RoR 4.  I have this json data to populate my chart rows

```
rows: [
  {c: [{v: "Week 1"}, [{v: 0}, {v: 3}, {v: 1}]]}, 
  {c: [{v: 0}]}, 
  {c: [{v: 0}]}, 
  {c: [{v: 0}]}
]
```

notice after the week 1 object another array of hashes(eg. `[{v: 0}, {v: 3}]`).

Is there anyway to remove the containing array to format the json properly

`{v: 0}, {v: 3}, {v: 1}`

I have tried using numerous methods(inject,map,etc.) and have not been able to remove the containing array.

```
 values = first_count.inject({}){|h,k| h[k] = 'v'; h}
```

I am formatting the data ruby and passing it to my chart via ajax.

Comment: There is no valid json property `{v: 0}, {v: 3}, {v: 1}` unless these hashes are packed into an array, exactly as in your input data.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you meant?

```
rows = {
  rows: [
        {c: [{v: "Week 1"}, [{v: 0}, {v: 3}, {v: 1}]]},
        {c: [{v: 0}]},
        {c: [{v: 0}]},
        {c: [{v: 0}]}
    ]
}

rows[:rows][0][:c].flatten!
```

which leaves `rows` with the value:

```
{
  rows: [
        {c: [{v: "Week 1"}, {v: 0}, {v: 3}, {v: 1}]},
        {c: [{v: 0}]},
        {c: [{v: 0}]},
        {c: [{v: 0}]}
    ]
}
```